# Click command not a function anymore

Tags: python, click

After applying the `@click.command()` decorator, the decorated function becomes a `Command` and cannot be called as a normal function anymore. However, it's still a callable, and if I pass the arguments as a list that are string, it seems to work.

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.argument('info', nargs=-1)
def hello(info):
    print(info)

hello(['asdf'])
```

This works, returning `(u'asdf')`. However when I do:

`hello([1234])` it  fail with `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. So should I consider a `Command` as its own thing and never try to call it through import?

Comment: you can always keep `hello()` as normal function and create other function which runs it and uses it in `@click.command() ... def other(...): hello(...)`

Comment: I see, so I will need to create another function that can be imported and called.

Comment: BWT: i'm not sure but normally when you run it as comman then probably it sends all arguments as strings - even if you use `123` - and you should do the same in this situation `help(['123'])` and inside function convert to integer.